# PHPunit test errors with `Parse error` on CI

Tags: php, phpunit, gitlab-ci

I'm unit testing my code with the help of `phpunit 9.3.8`. The tests run fine on my local dev environment (I'm running Windows 10, `PHP 7.4.2` with `Xdebug 2.9.2`) but fail because of a parse error when I try to run `phpunit` on Gitlab CI (The CI runs the latest alpine linux image).

The error is:

```
$ composer run test
> phpunit
PHPUnit 9.3.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Runtime:       PHP 7.3.23 with Xdebug 2.9.8
Configuration: /builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/phpunit.xml
Reporter
 ✘ Can set short message [6.05 ms]
   │
   │ ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'int' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
   │
   │ /builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/src/api/utilities/Reporter.php:21
   │ /builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/src/api/tests/ReporterTest.php:12
   │

// More errors

Time: 00:01.970, Memory: 310.00 MB
ERRORS!
Tests: 6, Assertions: 0, Errors: 6.
Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done [00:00.330]
PHP Warning:  fopen(/builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php on line 89
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main() /builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:61
PHP   3. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run() /builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:100
PHP   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->run() /builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:147
PHP   5. PHPUnit\Util\Printer->__construct() /builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:756
PHP   6. fopen() /builds/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:89
Code Coverage Report:    
  2020-10-13 10:12:09    
                         
 Summary:                
  Classes:  0.00% (0/11) 
  Methods:  0.00% (0/38) 
  Paths:    0.00% (0/7)  
  Branches:    0.00% (0/7)
  Lines:    0.00% (0/397)
Script phpunit handling the test event returned with error code 2
```

Line 21 of the `Reporter.php` file is below:

```php
<?php namespace utilities\Reporter;

/**
 * The Reporter class is responsible for returning data to the client.
 */
class Reporter
{
    /** This is the code of the answer.
     * (more comments)
     * @var int The status code.
     */
    private int $code; //<-- This is line number 21
```

And the line 12 of `ReporterTest.php` is:

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use utilities\Reporter\Reporter;

class ReporterTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $reporter;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->reporter = new Reporter(); // <-- Line 12 is here
    }
}
```

I'm using the fixtures function of PHPunit, defined as :

> PHPUnit supports sharing the setup code. Before a test method is run, a template method called setUp() is invoked. setUp() is where you create the objects against which you will test.

Comment: Type hinting of object properties is in PHP 7.4+ and this is running - *Runtime: PHP 7.3.23*

Comment: Damn, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type hinting of object properties is in [PHP 7.4](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2) and this is running

> PHPUnit 9.3.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Runtime: **PHP 7.3.23** with Xdebug 2.9.8

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a PHP version conflict,
for some reason `PHPUnit` is trying to parse it like older PHP versions where `private int $code;` is invalid (and `private $code;` should be used instead).

Oh, just noticed your Windows system is running `PHP 7.4`
but Gitlab CI image has `PHP 7.3.23` installed!